# Ag grid: column filters are not updating after adding the row

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have created Ag-grid with custom column filter. When I add the row in the table filter is not updating.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-custom-filter

[image]

Expert Advise please?

**HTML**

```
  <ag-grid-angular  #agGrid class="ag-theme-balham cis-ag-grid" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [rowSelection]="rowSelection" [rowData]="rowData" [suppressMenuHide]="true"
      [rowDragManaged]="true" [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
      (rowClicked)='onRowClicked($event)' (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" (valueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
       [gridOptions]="gridOptions" >
    </ag-grid-angular>
    <!-- ./ Ag-grid -->
```

**TS**

```
onCellValueChanged(params) {
    var col = params.column;
    switch (col.getId()) {
      case "name":
        this.refreshName(params.api, params.newValue);
        break;
    }
  }

refreshName(api, newValue) {
    var filter = api.getFilterInstance("name");
    var model = filter.getModel();
    filter.resetFilterValues();
    var filterWasActive = model !== null;
    if (filterWasActive) {
      if (model && model.values.indexOf(newValue) < 0) {
        model.values.push(newValue);
      }
      filter.setModel(model);
    }
  }
```

Adding the Row

```
 const addedRow = this.gridOptions.api.updateRowData({ add: [selectedView.data] });
      addedRow.add[0].setSelected(true);
      this.gridApi.getFilterInstance("name").resetFilterValues(); // Trying to refresh the filter
      this.gridOptions.api.ensureIndexVisible(addedRow.add[0].rowIndex, "top");
```

Comment: Please add a StackBlitz

Comment: Here the link stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-custom-filter. Click on 'Add random rows' It will add random rows but column filter is not updating(screenshot added H,P, etc.. not updated in filter)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add this line `this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();` after removing this line

```
this.filter4.onNewRowsLoaded();
```

to let ag-grid know that data was modified externally.

As per docs -

> onFilterChanged() - Informs the grid that a filter has changed. This
>   is typically called after a filter change through one of the filter
>   APIs.

Comment: One observation here is while adding or deleting the grid values, first time when open the column filter values are updated properly. Issue comes from second time onward after adding or deleting the values, no reset the filter values.

Comment: please check updated answer, your stakblitz example is not initializing this.filter4. Kindly correct the bugs before trying the solution

Comment: this.filter4.onNewRowsLoaded(); this works only for adding the rows but it is not working for deleting the row